# Does Fused Location Provider in Android Work in only Data enabled situation?

Tags: google-api, android-location, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation, android-gps

Will the Fused Location Provider in Android work without data connection.
If yes how could able to get location.Tahnk you in advance.

Comment: does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on what you set when you are building your LocationRequest object. If you set `LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` then it is guaranteed that the location is fetched by GPS